# Using spinnerPlugin on page load is giving error.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have 2 pages. Index.html and detail.html. On index.html, when I click login, I call this function

```
$('form').submit(function (event) { //Trigger on form submit        
    var options = { dimBackground: true };
    SpinnerPlugin.activityStart("Loading...", options);
});
```

It works perfectly. But on detail.html, I call this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = { dimBackground: true };
    SpinnerPlugin.activityStart("Loading...", options);
});
```

And it gives me the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SpinnerPlugin is not defined

I have installed the SpinnerPlugin using xml as well. Wat should I do? Why is it working on index.html and not on detail.html?

Comment: Do you actually load the plugin on detail.html?

Comment: I think you forgot to inject your plugin on detail.html page !

Comment: I did not injected it inside index.html as well. In phonegap, we just add a line <plugin name="cordova-plugin-spinner" source="npm"/> inside the config.xml and it works inside the project I guess.

Comment: @AliZia You gotta include cordova.js file in your html and register the plugin code in cordova's deviceready event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spinner plugin will only be available after the device ready event. This means that you should wrap your code with it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

function onDeviceReady() {
  var options = { dimBackground: true };
  SpinnerPlugin.activityStart("Loading...", options);
}
```